# Get logged in user's id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

How can I get the logged in user's UserId? I'm using the standard system generated AccountModel. I can get the username using:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

but I don't see the UserId field. I want to use the UserId as a foreign key for another table.

Comment: Simple Membership?  ASP.NET Membership?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're looking for [ProviderUserKey - Gets the user identifier from the membership data source for the user.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.provideruserkey.aspx)

```
object id = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
```

[Membership.GetUser() - Gets the information from the data source and updates the last-activity date/time stamp for the current logged-on membership user.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getuser.aspx)

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting:

Error 1 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser' does not contain a definition for 'GetUser'

Comment: Thanks, typo there, it was suppose to be `Membership`.

Comment: Membership.GetUser().UserName for the username instead of the internal membership database key

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

That's how its done in the partial views for current MVC (MVC5/EF6/VS2013) templates.

Correct me if I'm wrong, because I've seen Aviatrix's answers a lot, but what happens if more than one user has the same name in the database?

Comment: This solution is not possible if the user is already logged in and trying to change the current password.

Answer (score 10):

The best way to do so is to use the WebSecurty class

```
var memberId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
```

and don't forget to add `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` on top of your controller :)

Comment: As long as your provider follows the requirements to use an `int` as the Unique Identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Their are already very good answer but what i understood from your question is that you want to fetch data from database using id.so here is what you can do.

```
public List<ForeignkeyTable> RV()
{
 var email = User.Identity.Name;

Usertable m = db.Uusertables.Where(x => x.user_Email == email).SingleOrDefault();

 var id = m.user_Id;

var p = db.ForeignkeyTable.Where(x => x.user_fk_id == id).ToList();


return p;

}
```

This way you can return all the data from database of that id in foreignkey.