# <$G+$> Strange characters appearing in ASP.NET MVC5 Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

My helper in the view, which is intended to display the full name of a user who is registered in the application, and the username if logged in via 3rd party authentication.

```
@using MyApp.Models;

@helper GetUserName()
{
    if (User.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Application")
    {
        using (var db = new MyAppDbContext())
        {
            @db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId()).FullName
        }
    }
    else
    {
        @User.Identity.GetUserName()
    }
}
```

Then I use this helper:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-form pull-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + GetUserName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
    }
}
```

The name of my user is Proba234, and it displays like this:

[image]

Why are those strange characters (`<$G+$>`) appear, and how to get rid of them?

Comment: Is `User.Identity.GetUserName()` an extension method?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18451374/2270404 regarding `User.Identity.GetUserName()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like those funny characters are generated by helper. The probleem seems to be that the output of the helper is not meant to be consumed as regular `string`. Apparently it generates some control characters, which are meant to be there for Razor, but if we try to use the output as regular string (as `@Html.ActionLink()` expects its argument) they become visible.

To get rid of them, I shouldn't use the `GetUserName()` helper inside the @`Html.ActionLink()`, but get the UserName in the controller, and pass it via a property of the viewmodel. I shouldn't have that kind of logic in my view anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably some kind of feature or bug related with usage of helpers within Visual Studio Page Inspector, you probably won't see those tags under external browser. I reproduced it easily in VS 2013. A thread about it can be found for example on [ASP.NET forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1886922.aspx)

Comment: It is indeed visible in an external browser. The screenshot is from FireFox.