# unable to assign UserID in asp.net identity to a int value type

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-2

this is my controller action method-------

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PostPost(Post post)
    { 
     // previosly i was using simple membership to get id of logged in user
       // post.PostedBy = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
          post.PostedBy = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
           post.PostedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        ModelState.Remove("post.PostedBy");
        ModelState.Remove("post.PostedDate");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
   // now i am facing problem at this line. it is saying that
  //Operator '=='   cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'  
            var usr = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == post.PostedBy);
```

my code was working fine when i was using simple membership.what should i try to make it working. here, post is a class with property PostedBy as int and i want to assign current loggedIn userId value to this property.

Comment: I love that you have used the word "Post" 20 times in a single question, especially the method signature :)

Comment: hahaha what can i do ..... it's just a code i have not noticed that @DavidG

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer in this link: [How to get current user, and how to use User class in MVC5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448637/how-to-get-current-user-and-how-to-use-user-class-in-mvc5)

Check how the code is written in the answer:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

...

User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

if that didn't work please debug and trace the code and tell us what's the value of User.Identity ?

Comment: i am facing problem at the last line where it gives red underline that == operands cannot be applied to int and string. I have seen all the links given by u but problem still persists

Comment: sorry i didn't notice the comment written in your code, ok, for the table "Users" in the database which you are using here, what is the datatype of the column "Id" ?

Comment: Column Id is the default one provided by identity2.1. It is primary key with int datatype.I want to get this value and assign it to post table's PostedBy property.

Comment: I think it is somehow using the Id as a string, would you try writing the last line this way and tell me if that worked:
 post.PostedBy.ToString()