# ASP MVC 4 get user details using authentication token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient)
but I don't get it quite well,sorry I'm a totally noob for asp. So I already have the authorization token from the server after I successfully logged in. Now my question is it possible to get the user data for example username, first and lastname of the user using the authentication token. What I have so far is this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AuthenticateToken()
{
   string authToken = Request.Form["AuthenticationToken"];
   if (authToken.IsNullOrEmtpy())
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown authentication token");
   }

  // now get the user data from the api using the auth token here...
}
```

I hope my question make sense. Thank you.

Comment: what kind of authentication mechanims do you use

Comment: hi @lordkain, I have a login form where you can enter username and password, then that form will send post request to api then the api will give me the authencation token.

Comment: what API are you using?

Comment: its an asp web api

Comment: i mean are u using OWIN or? u are using default template VS for web api?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448637/how-to-get-current-user-and-how-to-use-user-class-in-mvc5

Comment: ah yes, I'm using the default template for VS web api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153342/discussion-between-lordkain-and-makubex).