# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity not populated after sign in

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-identity

So I'm using AspNet Identity and I'm trying to access the User session variable in `Http.Context.Current.User` after signing in. I've read online that it should be automatically populated once the sign in attempt is successful. However this doesn't seem to be the case for me.

This is my code:

```
  Dim email As String = txtEmail.Text
            Dim password As String = txtPassword.Text
            Dim user As ApplicationUser

            If Session("LocalNetwork") Then
                Await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(email, password, False, False))

                Dim y = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId

            End If
```

The signin is successful and I'm trying to access my UsersID but it returns null.

Web config:

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: Check out this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448637/how-to-get-current-user-and-how-to-use-user-class-in-mvc5

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't think that's my issue

Comment: No, it's not precisely your issue, but you can track it down ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because I was checking if the user was authenticated in the same request as updating them. So they wont be authenticated until the end of the request.